# AttributeError: 'FeedExporter' object has no attribute 'slot'

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this simple spider, when I call `scrapy crawl dataspider` it works fine and prints the item in the the output :

```
import json
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class dataspider(Spider):
    name='dataspider'
    start_urls=('https://www.google.com/finance/match?matchtype=matchall&ei=UVlPWNmDEYm_U7SqgvAH&q=AAPL',)
    def parse(self, response):
        j=json.loads( response.body.decode('utf-8') )
        yield j['matches'][1]
```

Outputs :

> {'t': 'AAPL', 'n': 'Apple Inc.', 'e': 'NASDAQ', 'id': '22144'}

However as soon as I try to save the item in a file using `scrapy crawl dataspider -o out.json` I get this error :

> AttributeError: 'FeedExporter' object has no attribute 'slot'

Traceback is :

```
2017-01-30 01:10:57 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method FeedExporter.close_spider of <scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter object at 0x7f31e2d8ab00>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 198, in close_spider
    slot = self.slot
AttributeError: 'FeedExporter' object has no attribute 'slot'
```

Earlier in the traceback I also have this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 187, in open_spider
    uri = self.urifmt % self._get_uri_params(spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 262, in _get_uri_params
    params[k] = getattr(spider, k)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 36, in logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1813, in getLogger
    return Logger.manager.getLogger(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1167, in getLogger
    raise TypeError('A logger name must be a string')
TypeError: A logger name must be a string
```

Any idea what the problem is ?

Comment: It seems like answer to your question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223700/why-does-scrapyd-throw-feedexporter-object-has-no-attribute-slot-exceptio
You should try to close out.json file before running crawler.

Comment: @EduardIlyasov apparently it was caused by `super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` in the __init__() method, the `super().__init__()` shouldn't have a self argument, as soon as I deleted it it worked again. No idea how it works however.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs advice worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running command with administrator permission and the issue is resolved.

Comment: What the issue you were having identical to the one in the question?  It appears that their resolution was quite a bit different...